# Binary addition and subtraction

Tags: arithmetic, binary

Assuming the sign-magnitude representation of binary numbers, what is the result of the `-6+29`?!

```
-6   ->    100110
29   ->    011101
```

The decimal result is `23` and there is no overflow for that. However, the binary addition shows `000011` with a `1` as carry bit. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Straightforward binary addition only works for twos-complement representation. Sign-magnitude represenation is more complicated, which is why nobody uses it.

Comment: Sign-magnitude is used by floating point numbers... kind of...